# MPPT Sunny Buddy (LT3652) + Solar Panel Voltage

Tags: solar-cell, mppt, sparkfun

I am having an issue using the sunny buddy mppt charger -

The PV panels I am using give a voltage of 11-12V but when I connect the battery to the mppt, the voltage drops to 4-5V. Does anyone know how I can address this problem?

Also the charging current does not go to 600mAh, as set using a resistor.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no such things as a "mppt".  Even if there was, it would be "MPPT".  It stands for *maximum power point tracking*, which describes the algorithm used.

Comment: Currents can't go to 600 mAh as that is a measurement of charge and not current...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your panel can't provide the power that the battery wants when charging.  It is also possible that whatever you are connecting the battery to is at the wrong voltage.

The power supply between the panel and the battery can't work magic.  It can convert from one voltage x current combination to another voltage x current combination.  However, it can never make more voltage x current (power) out than in.